# Finding angle of a particles after collision, don't know speeds after, only have one angle

Tags: particle-physics, collision, elasticity

An atomic nucleus of mass m (denoting this a), traveling with speed v, collides elastically with a target particle of mass 2m (denoting this b), initially at rest, and (the m particle) is scattered at 90 degrees. At what angle does the target particle move after the collision?

I know what you just two unknowns, like when you know both the angles but not the speeds of both particles after the collision, that you can find them by breaking it into components such as:

Px: $v_a = v_a ^{'}cos(\theta_a^{'})+2v_b^{'}cos(\theta_b^{'})$

Py: $0 = v_a ^{'}sin(\theta_a^{'})+2v_b^{'}sin(\theta_b^{'})$

and putting the equations together.

But without having the second angle I'm not sure what else to use tp fill in the gap that leaves. Using the conserved kinetic energy equation gives $v_a^2=v'^2_a+2v'^2_b$ which doesn't seem to help. Through a lot of equation manipulation I also have $tan(\theta) = v_a'/v_a$ but couldn't find a way to use that either.

Comment: The first thing you need to do is to account for the different masses of the busker and the target.  Next, what are the properties of *elestic* collisions?  Incidentally you apply this incorrectly: the kinetic energy is the sum of bullet and target.

Comment: Your conservation of kinetic energy equation is incorrect because the masses are different.

Comment: Oops, should have been $2v_b'$, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to draw a diagram.

The initial momentum of the incident particle is completely transferred to the target particle.

The incident particle momentum after collision is equal and opposite to a component of the total momentum of the target particle at right angles to the incident particle direction.

Using these ideas you have one unknown which is the component of the target velocity at right angles to the initial incident particle direction.

Kinetic energy conservation should enable you to find this component of velocity and hence the required angle.